# Using Classification_Report function in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

So how I understand this function works is that it splits a table into two and then compares the values to determine the prediction rate

Lets say I have a table:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5 
3          2          2          43         0
1          2          2          23         1
5          5          2          56         1
4          3          2          13         0
6          1          2          11         1

"Column 5" is label 0 or 1
```

I know that first 3 rows are 100% correct because I manually assigned labels to it, but row 4 and 5 were labeled using random forest classifier. I wanna see what the prediction rate is

I wanna use classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names), what would my "y_true", "y_pred" be? Im assuming target_names = 0,1

Answer (score 0):

y_true are the true labels of the samples and y_pred are the predictions made my the model. target_name lets you assign custom names to the class labels

classification_report repots the precision, recall, f1-score  and support of the model.

Example as shown in sklearn 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

For example the precision of class 0 is True Positive / True positive + False Positive which is 1/2 = 0.5